# Strange percent sign in netstat (192.168.8.16%31621:5555)

Tags: linux, bash, netstat

Does anyone know what the %-sign in the netstat output below means? I can't find anything in the man page nor on the web.

```
tcp6       0      0 192.168.8.16%31621:5555 192.168.8.65%3162:47107 TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 192.168.8.16%31621:5555 192.168.8.65%3162:47083 TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 192.168.8.16%31621:5555 192.168.8.65%3162:47256 TIME_WAIT
```

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe its just for better readability of ipv6 adresses and ports? dont have this output in my netstat...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a IPv6 [zone index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Link-local_addresses_and_zone_indices).